# Solution of an ODE: dy/dx=1/(x+y^2)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was going through past papers of ODEs course. I came across a question: solve $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{x+y^2},\qquad y(-2) = 0.$$ I have no clue how to proceed. I have suspicion that this equation has no closed form solution and may be there was a mistake in the question. Course is a basic course on ODEs. I will appreciate solution/hints/further reading.

Comment: Consider the equation for $dx/dy$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using $\frac{dx}{dy}$ we have $$x'-x=y^2$$ therefore $$xe^{-y}=\int y^2e^{-y}dy$$and so $$x=-(y^2+2y+2)+c e^{y}$$

Comment: ...And, since $y(-2)=0$, plugging $y=0$ in the RHS of the last equation should yield $x=-2$ in the LHS, thus, $c=0$. This yields $$y^2+2y+2=-x,$$ that is, $$y=-1\pm\sqrt{-x-1}.$$ Using the condition $y(-2)=0$ once again shows finally that the unique solution is defined for every $x\lt-1$ by $$y(x)=-1+\sqrt{-x-1}.$$